# Microatchitecture optimization for GPU code

Tags: performance, assembly, gpu, nvidia, perf

For x86 cpus there's a well-documented framework in the Intel Software Optimization Manual called Top-down Microarchitecture Analysis Method with the specific `perf` counters to analyze on each level.

I'm currently running some code on NVidia gpu geforce gtx 1050 and want to understand and measure performance bottlenecks related to its microarchitecture.

Is there a general approach to measure, analyze and tune GPU code performance similar to what exists for x86 CPUs?

Comment: Have you tried [looking at their website](https://developer.nvidia.com/performance-analysis-tools) ?

Comment: @Michael Sure, I first tried to find any ISA manual but it turned out that it is closed source

Comment: I was thinking more about the tools that they have there.

Comment: @Michael Yeah, The PAPI CUDA Component looks roughly speaking similar to what perf does. But is there any documentation on GPU pipeline and microarchetecture or this information is also closed?